# Text manipulation to form an equation

Tags: python, parsing, text, scripting, equation

a=0.77 ,b=0.2 ,c=0.20, d=0.79 ,z=(c+d), e=(z*a) ,output=(z+e)

I have a text file like above. I need a parser logic that will throw an equation like
output=(0.20+0.79)+((0.20+0.79)*a) what are some efficient ways to do it? Are there any libraries? Thank you!

Comment: Python has the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function which may be relevant here

Comment: Good lord, do NOT use `eval` on data read from external files.

Comment: if you would have `;` instead of `,` then you could use `exec(string)` to execute it as Python code. And you would have it (also with `;`) in file with extension `.py` then you could simply `import` as Python code. But all this would display only finall value `1.7523`. To get `(0.20+0.79)+((0.20+0.79)*a)` you would have to work like with string and `replace()` elements in string. OR you can check in [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) to work with `Symbolic Python` but it may also reduce `0.20+0.79` directly to `0.99`

Answer (score 0):

Primitive method is to work with strings and use `replace()`

---

First use `split(',')` to convert string to list

```
['a=0.77 ', 'b=0.2 ', 'c=0.20', ' d=0.79 ', 'z=(c+d)', ' e=(z*a) ', 'output=(z+e)']
```

Next use `.strip()` to remove spaces from ends and begins.

Next use `.split('=')` on every element to create nested lists.

```
[['a', '0.77'], ['b', '0.2'], ['c', '0.20'], ['d', '0.79'], ['z', '(c+d)'], ['e', '(z*a)'], ['output', '(z+e)']]
```

Next use `dict()` to create dictionary.

```
{'a': '0.77',
 'b': '0.2',
 'c': '0.20',
 'd': '0.79',
 'e': '(z*a)',
 'output': '(z+e)',
 'z': '(c+d)'}
```

And now you can get first `'a' : '0.77` to run `.replace('a', '0.77`)` on other items in dictionary. And repeate it with other values from dictionary.

So finally you could get dictionary

```
{'a': '0.77',
 'b': '0.2',
 'c': '0.20',
 'd': '0.79',
 'e': '((0.20+0.79)*0.77)',
 'output': '((0.20+0.79)+((0.20+0.79)*0.77))',
 'z': '(0.20+0.79)'}
```

and `output` has string `((0.20+0.79)+((0.20+0.79)*0.77))`

---

```
import sympy
import pprint

text = 'a=0.77 ,b=0.2 ,c=0.20, d=0.79 ,z=(c+d), e=(z*a) ,output=(z+e)'

parts = text.split(',')                     # create list
#print(parts)
parts = [item.strip() for item in parts]    # remove spaces
#print(parts)
parts = [item.split('=') for item in parts] # create tuples
#print(parts)
parts = dict(parts)                         # create dict
#print(parts)

pprint.pprint(parts)

for key1, val1 in parts.items():
    for key2, val2 in parts.items():
        parts[key2] = parts[key2].replace(key1, val1)

pprint.pprint(parts)

print('output:', parts['output'])
```