# Assign values from file 1 to file 2 in python

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

I have two text files.
Text file 1:  0=0.345,1=34.5,2=54.6,3=235.67
Text file 2 : (0+2)*(3+2)

Is there a python operation that will assign the corresponding numbers from text file 1 to text file 2? I am doing my computations in text file 2
Thanks!

Comment: you will have to load all as text, parse first text on your own and use `replace()` to replace values in second string. But better use letters instead of numbers becasue you have `0` in `(0+2)` but also in `0.345` and `replace()` may put new values in place of `0` in `0.345`

Comment: see similar problem: [Text manipulation to form an equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959168/text-manipulation-to-form-an-equation)

Comment: you have it also in your previous question [script to obtain a single equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961541/script-to-obtain-a-single-equation)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in both files is similar to the one you provided, you can store assignments from the first file in the dictionary and then map them into the equation from the second file.

```py
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f:
    file1 = f.read() # file1 = "0=0.345,1=34.5,2=54.6,3=235.67"
with open("file2.txt", "r") as f:
    file2 = f.read() # file2 = "(0+2)*(3+2)"

variables = {}
for equation in file1.split(","):
    var, value = equation.split("=")
    variables[var] = value
# variables = {'0': '0.345', '1': '34.5', '2': '54.6', '3': '235.67'}

operation = [variables.get(letter, letter) for letter in file2]
exec("result = " + "".join(operation)) # result = (0.345+54.6)*(235.67+54.6)
print(result) # 15948.885149999998
```

Comment: I dont want the output to be computed, can it remain like result = (0.345+54.6)*(235.67+54.6)

Comment: @Alex sure, just instead of using `exec` save it to variable as string: `s="result = " + "".join(operation)`